# Finding the particular solution of $T(t) = T_a + Ce^{-kt}$

Tags: calculus, integration

the following is the Newton’s Law of Cooling,

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = - k (T - T_a) $$
where T(t) is the temperature of object at time t, $T_a$ is the ambient temperature at 25 degrees Cc and k is the positive constant.

From that differential equation, I integrate it to get the general solution of -

$$ T(t) = T_a + Ce^{-kt} = 25 + Ce^{-kt} $$

I conducted an experiment of boiling water cooling down in room temperature of 25.

At 0min, it’s 100 Degrees C,

At 1 min, it’s 96

At 5 mins, it’s 88

using this data, I am trying to find the particular solution, but to do that, I need to find the constant $k$ before I go on to find the arbitrary constant, $C$ .  I am not sure on how to go about that. Thanks..

Comment: Are you allowed to use computer to fit a function to those points?

Comment: @Botond yes, i have more datas than that which is from 0-60 mins. I have used excel to graph out an exponential decay graph

Comment: Are you familiar with the python language?

Comment: @Botond nope. apparently I have to work with the Newton law of cooling equation and my datas collected to find out the particular solution.

Comment: @Botond I was thinking about using t=0 to find the constant C, and then using any other t value to find the other constant k. can this be done?

Comment: And what kind of method should you use? For example, from the $T(0)=100$, you can set $C=75$, and from the $T(5)=88$, you can set $k=\frac{1}{5}\log(\frac{25}{21}) \approx 0.034871$, but with a lot more data and some kind of fitting method, you can get the best fitting curve. But honestly, I don't know how to do that without a computer program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can linearize the equation:  $T ( t ) = 25 + Ce^{-kt}$

$T  -25= Ce^{-kt}$

$\ln(T-25)=\ln(C)-kt$

This is equivalent to

$y=a-kt$

This is a linear equation. Therefore it is possible to apply $\texttt{linear regression}$

Here you have to evaluate the parameters $a$ and $k$.

For this purpose you have to transform some values, which can be done easily with excel.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline t&T&\ln(T-25) \\ \hline 0&100&4.317488 \\ \hline1&96&4.262679 \\  \hline5&88&4.143135 \\  \hline \vdots&\vdots&\vdots \end{array}$$

**Remark**

Linear regression can be done in Excel with matrices. The formula is

$\textbf{b}=(\textbf{X} '\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf X'\textbf{y}$. For more detailed information look [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/382/), for instance. More specific:

$\textbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix} a\\ -k \end{pmatrix}, \quad\textbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}{} 1 &0 \\ 1 & 1\\ 1&5\\ \vdots & \vdots \end{pmatrix}\quad \textbf{y}=\begin{pmatrix} 4.317488\\ 4.262679\\ 4.143135\\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Consider the new variable $\Theta = T-T_0$ so the new DE reads

$$
\frac{d\Theta}{dt} = -k\Theta
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the first 2 set of data substitute them in your equation and you will get
$$k=ln((T 1-Ta)/(T 2-Ta)) / (t 2-t 1))$$

Then use $k$ to calculate independently $C$ in terms of the 3rd set of data.